# AngularJs - what's wrong with this directive?

Tags: angularjs

I have written the following directive, trying to make some common functionality for sorting rows in grids (note that this is my first directive, so be gentle with me in case of huge misconceptions):

```
function AddSortDirectiveToModule(module) {
    module.directive('sortableHeader', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template:
                '<span>'+
                    '<a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="sortBy(\'{{colName}}\')">{{colText}}</a>' +
                    '<span class="gly {{icon}}"></span>' +
                '</span>',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                colName: '@',
                colText: '@',
                reverse: '=',
                predicate: '=',
            },
            controller: function ($scope) {
                $scope.icon = $scope.predicate == $scope.colName ? ($scope.reverse ? "gly-sort-by-attributes-alt" : "gly-sort-by-attributes") : "";
                $scope.sortBy = function(colNam) {
                    if ($scope.predicate == colNam) {
                        if ($scope.reverse == true) {
                            $scope.predicate = '';
                            return;
                        }
                        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
                    } else {
                        $scope.reverse = false;
                    }
                    $scope.predicate = colNam;
                };
            }
        };
    });
}
```

I use it like this:

```
<sortable-header col-text="Text" col-name="PropName" reverse="reverse" predicate="predicate" />
```

...and when I click on the generated link that is supposed to do the sorting, I get the following error (which makes no sense to me):

> [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'colName' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 3 of the expression [{{colName}}] starting at [colName}}].

I know that the problem is related to the `{{colName}}` in the template, but I can't see why this is a problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think... predicate: '=', its the (，)

Comment: @daniel I have just tried removing the comma after `predicate` but nothing has changed.

Comment: You can't use `{{ }}` inside an ng-click. It expects an expression, not surrounded by or containing `{{ }}`, like `ng-click="sortBy(colName)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give this template a try:

```
'<span>'+
    '<a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="sortBy(colName)">{{colText}}</a>' +
    '<span class="gly {{icon}}"></span>' +
'</span>',
```

Also instead of the `href="javascript:void(0)"` you should use `href="#"` and `$event.preventDefault();` in the `ngClick`

Comment: No need for preventDefault. Simply use `<a href="" ng-click="...">`. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/a

Comment: I apologize if I know nothing, but isn't `href=""` considered invalid?

Comment: By whom? This is the angular documented way of making ng-clickable links.

Comment: @JBNizet, @Jon-Snow You were right. It works with `sortBy(colName)`. Now the only problem is that the `{{icon}}` renders nothing.

Comment: @NoOne make sure it is actually defined on the scope, you can also use `ng-class` like so `<span class="gly" ng-class="icon"></span>`

Comment: @JonSnow Thanks for the `ng-class` suggestion. It is indeed better that way. However, I used to have the `icon` on the scope and I had to move it out because I could not see a way to access the variables required to construct it there. I don't know if I am missing sth. Perhaps I could inject the `$scope` to the directive? I don't think I have tried this approach...

Comment: @JonSnow However, the `icon` should be changed dynamically by the controller, so I am not sure if it could be only on the scope definition.

Comment: Adding the `icon: '@'` in the scope and keeping the rest as it was didn't help either.

Comment: @NoOne I meant that you need to define the icon in the controller.

Comment: Thanks. I needed to set it in the `sortBy()` function. Silly me was doing it outside of it...